# Asymptotic expansion of the confluent Heun function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Is the asymptotic expansion of the confluent Heun function known??

The confluent Heun's differential equation is given by

\begin{equation}
 y''(z) + \left( \epsilon + \frac{\gamma}{z}+ \frac{\delta}{z-1} \right) y'(x) + \left(\frac{\alpha z-q}{z(z-1)} \right) y(z)=0
\end{equation}

One of the solution, $Hc(\epsilon,\delta,\gamma,\alpha,q;z)$ , is defined by
$$ Hc(\epsilon,\delta,\gamma,\alpha,q;z=0) = 1 ,\\
 Hc'(\epsilon,\delta,\gamma,\alpha,q;z=0) = -\frac{q}{\gamma}.$$

I wonder if the asymptotic expansion of this function at $z\to -\infty$ is known. Thank you so much!

Comment: $\infty$ is an irregular singular point of the equation, looking for a solution in the form $(-z)^A e^{B z}$ and equating the leading terms, we get that the solution can grow as $c_1 (-z)^{-\alpha/\epsilon}$ or as $c_2 (-z)^{\alpha/\epsilon - \gamma - \delta} e^{-\epsilon z}$ when $z \to -\infty$.

Comment: Yes, we know solutions of the form $(-z)^A e^{B z}$. However, do we know the behavior of the above defined $Hc$ at large $(-z)$? That's the hard part which I am not sure what to do.